# Installing Pypotrace for python?

Tags: python

Did anybody manage to install `pypotrace` or is able to install `mingwin` it's like mission impossible for me I've passed the last 12 hours trying to found out how but nothing is working and description are poor please could any body help?  This is where you can get it:
[pypotrace web site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypotrace)

Comment: Which version of python, which operating system, what have you tried?

Comment: hello sir !  i am using Python2.7.6 under Win 7  32 bit

Comment: i have follow the discription on the link above and i have download and extract the rar to c:/src  and but when i open msys and chane directories to src and then to each one of them and use ./configure;make  it tell me that distitulis is missing

Comment: i searched for a while then i found out that Cython must be installed so i download the .tar and execute the cmd python setup.py install after cd and it tells me that there is a pb vcvarsall.bat none found

Comment: You need the windows installer - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working in windows you need the following steps:

1. You may need the python distutils package - `pip install -U distuilts` should do the job.
2. You will also need Cython - the windows installers are [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython).
3. You need to install [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) and **make sure it is working** in
       msys mode - run msys and you should get a command prompt in it type
       gcc --version and make sure you get a sensible reply.
       also make sure your python runs from within msys
4. Do the required downloads:

   - [potrace source](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading),
   - [agg source](http://www.antigrain.com/download/index.html) *site broken* or the [GitHub](https://github.com/ghaerr/agg-2.6/) zip file [here](https://github.com/ghaerr/agg-2.6/archive/master.zip),
   - potrace source from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pypotrace/pypotrace-0.1.2.tar.gz#md5=09011f27461722b15dc4742d45c97532) and unzip it.
5. The follow the instructions at the link you gave and tell us where they stop working.

Comment: i am opening msys directly from the folder Msys and it shoes  DELL@DELL-PC ~  is that mean that it is working ??$

Comment: Do you have ez_install.py and is it on your path?

Comment: Added link to windows Cython.

Comment: how !!!   i did  told that cython is not working too it told : unable to find  vcvarsall.bat

Comment: sorry i have notice ur link above and cython is installed now

Comment: how to link it to windows ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  You might need to add the location that it installed to to your path.

Comment: thank u sir Cython is installed now but u told to "Added link to windows Cython." i dont know how to do it but in python now when i execute import cython it work with no error

Comment: the link for agg source does nothing for me... Doesn't popup a dialog box to download it. There isn't any code in the index.html file when I check the file via my browser...

Comment: @ShanerM13 - I have added a new link to download the source from github

Comment: What a baller! Thank you very much! But now the distutils link is broken.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that inside of the potrace source (potrace-1.16.win64.zip) doesn't have a file called configure (or anything close to the word configure for that matter)... so when I run ./configure; make, it doesn't recognize it as a command or file. Does that file need to be manually created with a certain set of permissions?

Comment: I have replaced the distuilts link with a pip command that works for me. The file `potrace-1.16.win64.zip` is __not__ _source code_ it is the pre-compiled binary for windows but you need the source for the header files - this is in `potrace-1.16.tar.gz` at the same link.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was so much of a pain that I ported potrace to python directly rather than using hooks and requiring local compile.

`pip install potracer`

https://github.com/tatarize/potrace

I implemented the same API as `pypotrace` so it should be fairly painless.