# Installing Pypotrace for python

Tags: python, gcc

On a thread supposedly detailing how to install Pypotrace on Windows ([Installing Pypotrace for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221813/installing-pypotrace-for-python/31111506?noredirect=1#comment50248824_31111506)), someone was told:

> "You need to install `mingw` and make sure it is working in `msys` mode - run `msys`and you should get a command prompt in it type `gcc --version` and make sure you get a sensible reply. also make sure your `Python` runs from within `msys`."

In response to the comment that

*"You should get a command prompt in it type `gcc --version` and make sure you get a sensible reply"*

I noted that I don't- I get `"command not found."` What should I do to
resolve this issue?

*"Also make sure your `Python` runs from within `msys`."*

How can I check this?

In response to the question

*"Do you have `ez_install.py`?*"

I do. But *"Is it on your path?"* only leaves me wondering: Which path?

Is it possible to explain any of this clearly, without skipping important issues like what programs are being used, or what to do when something isn't working, and what paths are meant?

Comment: "Path" means system path... I guess. You should add appropriate path to `ez_install.py` to your `os.environ` dict

Comment: Also `command not found` error points to same issue: path to called program is not added to your system path

Comment: How do I "add appropraite path to my os.environ dict"???
Is this in Msys, or Cygwin, or by editing some Python script, or... what???

Comment: Maybe if people were more concerned about communicating clearly and helping people, and less with formatting, this site might actually be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your `system path` with `gcc` and `easy_install` paths as below:

`import os`

`os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path_to_your_executable_file`

where `path_to_your_executable_files` should be a `string` like `"C:\\Program Files\\Python27"`.

Also (for Windows OS) you can do the same step-by-step with this instructions: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Comment: How? Gcc isn't a Cygwin or Msys command, and apparently isn't a separate program.
And "easy_install" is... a python script?

Comment: just find folder e.g. `C:\\MinGW\\bin` which contains `gcc.exe` and use it as `path_to_your_executable_file`. same for `easy_install` (try `C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages`)

Comment: And where you wrote ["PATH"] I put what? "gcc.exe" didn't work: "KeyError."

Comment: No, you should leave the word "PATH" as it is! `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep` you shouldn't make any corrections to this part

Comment: I had tried that; the python console didn't report an error message, but Cygwin and Msys and MinGW all report "gcc" is not recognised as a command.

Comment: Please check if your paths really added: Start menu-->right click on My Computer--> Properties--> Advanced System Settings--> Environment Variables--> in System Variables field find "Path"--> double-click--> check if your paths added to the end of list

Comment: Nope.
Even restarted the machine, manually entered "gcc" and the path into the environmental variables (along with temp, etc.), but that didn't work.

Comment: If you done everything wright then print in `Python` shell `import os`   `os.environ['PATH']` It should display all system paths that you got. Are your last added paths present in list?

Comment: Apparently (I followed some MS instructions and installed them manually as %APPDATA% since nothing seemed to change using the Python command.
G++ and GCC still aren't recognised as commands.